# video stream: "onBWDone: undefined" and video doesn't play

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, amazon-s3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to stream a video from Amazon's CloudFront/S3 service. Despite my filename being correct, and a "NetConnection.Connect.Success" status, my NetConnection onBWDone callback is giving me an "undefined" error and the video doesn't play or show up anywhere on the stage. The connection reports that it's successful so I don't know where the problem lies. Here is my code:

```
var amazonCloudFrontDomain:String = "myCloudFrontDistributionID.cloudfront.net";
var amazonCloudFrontStreamURL:String = "rtmp://" + amazonCloudFrontDomain + "/cfx/st/";
var videoFileName:String = "myVideo.flv";

Security.allowDomain(amazonCloudFrontDomain);
Security.allowDomain("rtmp://" + amazonCloudFrontDomain);
Security.allowDomain(amazonCloudFrontStreamURL);


var client:Object = new Object();
client.onBWDone   = function(e){trace("onBWDone: " + e);}
client.onMetaData = function(e){trace("onMetaData: " + e);}
client.onCuePoint = function(e){trace("onCuePoint: " + e);}


var video:Video = new Video(300, 400);  //  create a new Video item and set its width and height
video.x = 0;  //  position the video's x position
video.y = 0;  //  position the video's y position
var duration:Number;  //  use this later to get the duration of the video being played
this.addChild(video);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();  //  variable for a new NetConnection
nc.client = client;
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netConnectionStatusHandler,false,0,true);
nc.connect(amazonCloudFrontStreamURL);  //  set the nc variable to null

var ns:NetStream;
function netConnectionStatusHandler(e):void
{
    switch(e.info.code)
    {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
            trace("S3 Connected");

            ns = new NetStream(nc);  // create a variable for a new NetStream connection & connect it to the nc variable
            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamStatusHandler);  //  add a listener to the NetStream to listen for any changes that happen with the NetStream
            ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, netStreamAsyncErrorHandler);  //  add a listener to the NetStream for any errors that may happen
            ns.client = client;

            video.attachNetStream(ns);  // attach the NetStream variable to the video object
            video.smoothing = true;
            video.deblocking = 1;

            ns.bufferTime = 5;  // set the buffer time to 5 seconds
            ns.play(videoFileName);  //  tell the netstream what video to play and play it
            break;
    }
    trace(e.info.code);
}


function netStreamAsyncErrorHandler(Event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
{
    // trace(event.text);  // this will handle any errors with video playback
}

function netStreamStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    trace(event.info.code);  // this will handle any events that are fired when the video is playing back
    switch(event.info.code)  //  switch statement to handle the various events with the NetConnection
    {

        case "NetStream.Buffer.Full":  //  when the buffer is full fire the code below
            ns.bufferTime = 10;  // set buffer time to 10 seconds       break;
        case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":  //  when the buffer is empty fire, code below
            ns.bufferTime = 10;  // set buffer time to 10 seconds
        break;
        case "NetStream.Play.Start":  //  when the video starts playing, fire the code below
            ns.bufferTime = 10;  // set the buffer time to 10 seconds
        break;
        case "NetStream.Seek.Notify":  // when you seek with the scrubber it sends a notify signal of the time
            ns.bufferTime = 10;  // set the buffer time to 10 seconds
        break;
        case "NetStream.Seek.InvalidTime":  // when you release the scrubber ahead of the video that has been loaded, you get this error.  it will jump you back to the last frame that has been loaded
            ns.bufferTime = 10;  // set the buffer time to 10 seconds
        break;
        case "NetStream.Play.Stop":  // when you reach the end of the video
            ns.pause();  // pause the video
            ns.seek(1);  // seek the video to the first frame
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the console output:

```
S3 Connected
netConnectionStatusHandler: NetConnection.Connect.Success
onBWDone: undefined
NetStream.Play.Reset
NetStream.Play.Start
```

...and nothing happens. No video, no audio, nothing. Can anyone see any problems with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that not all streaming applications have to use the onBWDone  function, so if they don't use it, it probably passes null or undefined to the function instead of the kbps.

So you're problem is likely with the `e` in your trace statement below:

```
client.onBWDone   = function(e){trace("onBWDone: " + e);}
```

Also, the function does not recieve an event object, but rather a `... rest` array that usually only has one item in it. try this instead:

```
client.onBWDone   = function(... rest){  //
    if(rest && rest.length > 0){  //since the function might not get any data, you need to check before trying to trace it out
        trace("onBWDone: " + rest[0]); //this is the kbps of the bandwidth available
    }
};
```

You can learn more at the Adobe docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7ffa.html

**EDIT**

In regards to your video path:

Flash Media Server applications are accessed in the following format over rtmp:  "server:port/application/instance". For VOD, instance is the name of your file and for FLV's it doesn't require the extension.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773cfae-7ff3.html

Comment: Thank you, very nice...that seemed to clear up the "onBWDone: undefined" error, although I don't know whether or not null value for "rest" is a concern or not for my CloudFront application. Also the bandwidth available variable sounds interesting too, I didn't know about that. The video still doesn't play, though...hopefully this helps close in on an answer for that.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  Have you tried using a pre-built player to see if maybe the problem in on the server?  Try connecting with the strobe player:  http://www.osmf.org/configurator/fmp/

Comment: onBWDone is only used to get the bandwidth of the connection, purely optional, so having the value passed to it be null won't affect your program at all.

Comment: Check the answer I just posted. It's now working as a result of removing the file extension on my videoFileName string.

Comment: You must have something in your FMS application that is messing up the .flv thing. By default, it will accept the file with or without the .flv extension.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
var videoFileName:String = "myVideo.flv";
```

to

```
var videoFileName:String = "myVideo";
```

and now it works. For some reason, excluding the file extension makes it work for me. I don't know why...strange.